# I need a php RegEx to find modx snippet call in html content

Tags: php, regex, modx

My regex is very-very weak, I need help writing [and hopefully understanding] a php regex to find a modx snippet call in the content field of a resource and extract one of the attributes of that call. The call will look like this:

```
[[ShowVideo? &path=`path/to/somevideo.mp4` &w=`960`&h=`540` &playlist=`true`]]
```

or possibly called un-cached

```
[[!ShowVideo? &path=`path/to/somevideo.mp4` &w=`960`&h=`540` &playlist=`true`]]
```

What I need to extract from that is the "path/to/somevideo.mp4" value from the path attribute.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your help guys - here is the completed snippet in case anyone is interested:

```
<?php

$rid = $modx->resource->get('id'); // this resource id

$children = $modx->getChildIds($rid,1); // get one level of child ids

$pattern = '~\[\[!?ShowVideo[^\]]*&?path=`([^`]*)`~'; // thanks Crayon Violent

$myPlaylist = ''; // output to placeholder

$listItems = ''; // list thumbs with link

$index = 1; // not actually used

$parents = $modx->getParentIds($rid); // get the parent id array

if(!$children){

    // try siblings 
    $children = $modx->getChildIds($parents[0]); // get children of immediate parent

    array_unshift($children, $parents[0]); // prepend immediate parent id

}else{

    // must be a parent folder?
    array_unshift($children, $rid); // prepend this id

}

$videos = $children; // just for readbility

foreach($videos as $video){

    $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $video); // get the first resource object

    if ($resource->get('id') == $rid){ // figure out if this is the current video [to add a css class]

        $current = ' current';

    }else{

        $current = '';

    }

    if($resource){ 

        $rescontent = $resource->getContent(); // get the unprocessed! content field

        if(preg_match($pattern, $rescontent, $matches)){ // thanks again crayon!

            $listItems .= $modx->getChunk('PlayListItems', array( // get the output chunk & populate it's placeholders

                'videopath' =>  $modx->makeUrl($resource->get('id')),
                'thumbnail' => $resource->getTVValue('PageThumbnail'),
                'current' => $current,

            ));

        }

    }

    $index++; // again ~ not used

}


$myPlaylist = $modx->getChunk('PlayListWrapper', array( // get and populate the wrapper chunk

    'ListItems' =>  $listItems,

));


return $myPlaylist; // output!
```

Comment: Why would you do that? This makes no sense if you are using Modx. You can simply use `$path` in your ShowVideo-snippet.

Comment: Sorry, no I cant. these ShowVideo snippets are embedded in a nested group of resources content fields ~ basically I am iterating through the set of resources looking for which ones have the ShowVideo snippet in them. [I'm building a playlist based on the folder hierarchy of the video resources.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
preg_match('~&path=`([^`]*)`~',$string,$match);
// $match[1] will have the value
```

If it needs to be a little more explicit:

```php
preg_match('~\[\[!?ShowVideo[^\]]*&path=`([^`]*)`~',$string,$match);
// $match[1] will have the value
```

Comment: Thanks Crayon, there's that regex that makes my head hurt. going to tinker with this right now and see how it works out. :)

Comment: I've changed the expression to '~\[\[!?ShowVideo[^\]]*&?path=`([^`]*)`~' because the &path= may sometimes be replaced as &amp;path= [by tinymce] seems to work, just wondering if it is still correct

Comment: That would cover if & is sometimes not present but it won't cover the &amp; I think since you are using the 2nd regex you can probably just remove the & from the pattern completely

Answer (score 2):

Don't overcomplicate things, keep it simple:

```
preg_match('#path=`([^`]+)#', $input, $matches);
```

[Working demo](http://regexr.com?3503t).

Comment: Wow - fast responses, thanks guys! Looking at Crayon's second solution may be best as there could be several modx tags buried in the content. yours appears to search for just the outer braces? [but thanks anyway!!]

Comment: This one just extracts the `path` attribute value. @Crayon's second example explicitly only finds `path` attributes within a `ShowVideo` element. It's up to you whether you need that kind of specificity.